# First Changed Value among different values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 5 columns in history table where every time new record is creating while changing the status of loan for a particular ID_ 256 :

```
 hist_id    Status   Changed_by  Loan_no    ID_
 1         Active     X          123456    256
 2         Inactive   Y          123456    256
 3         Active     Z          123456    256
 4         Active     K          123456    256
 5         Inactive   L          123456    256
```

I have 3 columns in main table (currently stored)

```
Status   Changed_by  Loan_no    ID_
Inactive   L          123456    256
```

Question:

I want the Username (Changed_By) who changed status of particular Id_ of loan 123456 for the first time?

Answer should be (Y who change first the status from Active to Inactive):

```
2         Inactive   Y          123456    256
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g SQL plus

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best solution to your problem but it serves the purpose:

```
select h2.* from history h1
inner join  history as h2  on h2.Loan_no = h1.Loan_no and h2.hist_id = h1.hist_id + 1
where h1.Loan_no = 123456
and h2.status != h1.status
limit 1
```

To view all the records who changed the status of the id of loan 123456 remove the limit as shown below:

```
select h2.* from history h1
inner join  history as h2  on h2.Loan_no = h1.Loan_no and h2.hist_id = h1.hist_id + 1
where h1.Loan_no = 123456
and h2.status != h1.status
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution using `ROW_NUMBER()` rather than joins:

```
SELECT ChangeLog.Changed_by
FROM (SELECT hist.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hist.ID_ ORDER BY hist.hist_id) Change_Num
FROM dbo.history hist) ChangeLog
WHERE ChangeLog.Change_Num = 2 AND ChangeLog.ID_ = 256
```

This also assumes the best way to chronlogize the history records for a given ID is by ordering on the `hist_id` column. If your schema contains a better column to determine chronology, you can replace `ORDER BY hist.hist_id` with `ORDER BY hist.<better_column>`.